# Printing 9 lines counting from 0-9 not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started off trying to have my code return me 9 lines counting from 0-9

```
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789       
0123456789
```

so on and so forth.
and instead I get this from my output

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

My code

```
def countdown(count):
    while (count <= 9):
        print ([count]*10)
        count += 1

countdown(0)
```

I know where the brackets are coming from and I've tried getting rid of these but every time I try to run without them `[count]` my code comes out a mess.  I know I've read about transferring data to str but though I've tried I haven't been able to figure this out yet.

question 1 is how do I fix this so that I can get it to do what I originally asked of it.

question 2 is more or less me wondering if there is something I can do to get rid of the `[ ]` and , from my current output so that I don't make this same mistake again.

Comment: Do you just want to print the same text "0123456789" 9 times?

Comment: yes, see this guy i have been dating does a lot of coding and Ive been really getting into it lately but he never wants to show me anything.  So I have been trying to pick up on things on my own so I'm trying to approach things as I have an idea to see if I can figure it out and if I bump into an issue I get as close as I can and then try to find help when I cant find it in the reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[]` comes from `[count]`, which is a list that contains one element `count`. You don't need it here.

To print `9` lines of `0`-`9`, that suggests nested loops, and perhaps `range`. 
Don't hard code `9` and `10` into the code, pass it as argument of the function. Here's a piece of code with some problems:

```
def countdown(count):
    for i in range(count):
        for j in range(count):
            print(j)

countdown(10)
```

The output has `9` times of `0`- `9`, but each number is in its own line. **I didn't give you the working code**, here's a hint: loop up the manual of `print`, how to print something without starting a new line?

Comment: that would be by saying for instance

        print (i, end='')

correct?

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like as shown below:

```
def countdown(count):
    while (count <= 9):
        print (''.join(str(x) for x in range(0,10)))
        count += 1

countdown(0)
```

Also, [somevalue] * 10 will create a list with 10 elements where each element == somevalue.
For. eg. [0] * 10 is [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

[1,1 ] * 2  is [1,1,1,1]

Comment: Consider using for count in range(0, 9) instead of a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use for loops. Depending on if you want an int or string to print out there are two ways I can think of doing this while being as literal as possible about the answer.

If all you need is to print the numbers to the screen a string should suffice.

```
def countdown():
for i in range(0,9):        #Iterate for 9 lines
    x=""                    #Using string x
    for j in range(0,10):   #Iterate through numbers 0-9 which is actually ten digits
        x += str(j)         #convert the int j to a string and add it to string x
    print(x)
```

If your trying to output an int convert the string to int an before printing.

```
def countdown():
for i in range(0,9):        #Iterate for 9 lines
    x=""                    #Using string x
    for j in range(0,10):   #Iterate through numbers 0-9 which is actually ten digits
        x += str(j)         #convert the int j to a string and add it to string x        
    y = int(x)              #convert the string x to int y
    print(y)
```

In either case your shell should print this:

```
>>> countdown()
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
```

You were attempting to use a list which could achieve a similar result but not what you asked for.

Comment: this is an interesting way of doing this, now say you wanted to iterate each number in the range

                0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
                1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 

etc
how would you then cause the iteration to print in this fashion?

Comment: Using my example on line 2 extend the range to 10 like so `for i in range(0,10):`.

On line 5 use i instead of j. So Change `x += str(j) ` to `x += str(i) `.

This should produce the result you desire.

Comment: As a side note, if you are working with others it's best to make your code as literal as possible so they can also understand it. Remember to be kind and comment your code. It will save time and make the process go far smoother especially for new learners.